# Does apex class constructor executes multiple times?

Tags: apex

I am asking this question to give clarification to somebody.  The controller constructor executes at page load. But does it executes during every ajax requests through apex function? Is there any link which proves this if it is Yes/No.

Comment: By Ajax you mean asynchronous JavaScript remoting, or maybe visualforce `rerender` statement?

Comment: By rerender using action function

Comment: ok, I updated my post then.

Answer (score 4):

No constructor are called only on page load and not on every ajax request.

You can prove it by example something like below:

Controller:

```
global with sharing class AccountRemoter {

public String accountName { get; set; }
public static Account account { get; set; }
public AccountRemoter() {
    System.debug('### I ma here');
 } // empty constructor

@RemoteAction
global static Account getAccount(String accountName) {
    account = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Type, NumberOfEmployees 
               FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountName];
    return account;
}
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountRemoter">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRemoteAccount() {
    var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
        accountName, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this
                document.getElementById('remoteAcctId').innerHTML = result.Id
                document.getElementById(
                    "{!$Component.block.blockSection.secondItem.acctNumEmployees}"
                    ).innerHTML = result.NumberOfEmployees;
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                    event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
}
</script>

<input id="acctSearch" type="text"/>
<button onclick="getRemoteAccount()">Get Account</button>
<div id="responseErrors"></div>

<apex:pageBlock id="block">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="blockSection" columns="2">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="firstItem">
            <span id="remoteAcctId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="secondItem">
            <apex:outputText id="acctNumEmployees"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Note that in debug log constructor is called only once when page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the constructor doesn't need to be called at all when invoking `remoteAction` as it static method.

So answering your question - **calling the `remoteAction` has nothing in common with invoking the constructor**. If your `remoteAction` method is defined inside the controller class, then - of course - constructor will be called on controller initialization. However, it's legal to call `remoteAction` from different class which might not be a controller, moreover it might not have explicit constructor. No constructor will be called anyway then.

for example:

```
global class SomeClass{
 @RemoteAction global static void runRemote(){
    //some logic;
 }
}
```

and then, no matter what your controller is:

```
SomeClass.runRemote(function(result, event){
    // some logic;
});
```

**UPDATE:**

As you are asking about the `actionFunction` and `rerender` - that's the second way of calling Apex methods from javaScript. Using `actionFunction` let you maintain state between postbacks, in opposite to stateless `remoteAction`, but again - the constructor is not called each time you call `actionFunction`.

Documentation is clear about that.

[*Using Constructors*:](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_constructors.htm)

> A constructor is code that is invoked when an object is created from the class blueprint.

and [*Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Get Requests*:](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm)

> 1. The constructor methods on the associated custom controller or controller extension classes are called, instantiating the controller objects.